# Do images download fully before they are re sized by html or css code?

Tags: html, css, photo

Basically exactly what the question asks. Do images on a website download the full file before re sizing them. I have a bunch of pictures and I use html to resize the images down to thumbnails to easily display on the page. However, these images take way to long to load while they are only 100px x 100px big. My only explanation is that it is downloading the entire file before re sizing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. The full image is downloaded.

If the source url is 1000x1000 and you size it on the screen to 100x100, it still has to load the entire image.

You should store the thumbnail at 100x100 and the full size at 1000x1000 and reference each when appropriate.

Comment: That is what I thought thank you. The answer will be accepted as soon as it lets me.